# Can't publish to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm getting this error when I try to publish my shiny app to shinyapps.io.

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: shinyapps-upload.s3.amazonaws.com
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
  Failed to parse C:/Users/charles/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpw55Twl/file50e07d6067e2/old/ui_ - Copy.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
2: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
  Failed to parse C:/Users/charles/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpw55Twl/file50e07d6067e2/old/ui___.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
3: In fileDependencies.R(file) :
  Failed to parse C:/Users/charles/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpw55Twl/file50e07d6067e2/server - Copy.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.
Timing stopped at: 0.05 0.03 0.08
Execution halted
```

Comment: hum, same for me

Comment: Same for me. I think shinyapps is having an issue on their end

Comment: Seems to be resolved now.  Definitely a shinyapps issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got a near identical error...

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Could not resolve host: shinyapps-upload.s3.amazonaws.com Calls: <Anonymous> ... uploadCloudBundle -> uploadBundle -> http -> <Anonymous> Execution halted
```

---

### Updating RStudio software was the fix.

Run RStudio > Help > Check for Updates

---

The update also resolved these other errors I ran into...

```
Could not resolve host: api.shinyapps.io
```

and

```
Error in `POST()`: ! <https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/11071383/deploy> failed with HTTP status 409 Unable to dispatch task for application=11071383 as there are 1 tasks already in progress. This is most likely a transient error. Please try again in a bit. If this error persists please contact support. Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─rsconnect::deployApp(...)
 2.   └─client$deployApplication(application, bundle$id, space)
 3.     └─rsconnect:::POST_JSON(service, authInfo, path, json)
 4.       └─rsconnect:::POST(...)
 5.         └─rsconnect:::httpRequestWithBody(...)
 6.           └─rsconnect:::handleResponse(httpResponse, error_call = error_call)
 7.             └─rsconnect (local) reportError(unlist(json$error))
 8.               └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 9.                 └─rlang::abort(...) 
Execution halted
```

Hopefully that helps! If not, try publishing fewer and/or smaller files to run on much less memory and processing power. It may appear to be below 1 GB of memory or whatever constraint your account has on ShinyApps, but in reality, your application memory usage for example is higher than RStudio shows you within its recorded intervals.